# netty ssl key exchange mode，how to use TLS-PSK mode with netty

Tags: java, netty, tls1.3, netty4, tls-psk

We are using Netty4, and we plan to expand SSL security mode of Netty, I am not sure whether Netty4 supports PSK key exchange mode, have the guidance of those who know this aspect, thank you very much

Comment: What is your question ? Where are you stuck exactly ?